# 2 Partitions are currectly active on /dev/sda

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows. While installing Ubuntu, I chose to `erase and install Ubuntu` option. Now, there are no partitions on my disk.

Now, I want to create partitions, but I'm getting the following error while using gparted:

```
2 Partitions are currently active on /dev/sda
```

Can someone help me to partition my disk.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to create partitions?  Your system is set up correctly now.  To change partitions you need to boot from Ubuntu installer USB(or make new one) and use try Ubuntu option.  Gparted will be on it.  Changing/moving partitions can corrupt or lose data so backup first.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to partition the disk that's running Ubuntu. You can't partition or resize an existing partition of a disk in use.

You need to run Ubuntu from another disk, such as booting the Ubuntu installation image from a USB stick. Also the partition you wish to modify can't be mounted when attempting to change it.